# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect error occured while load testing on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I used django web service post method.I want to load multiple number of threads users ex(100) at the same time load.Ramp up period is 1 sec.loop count is 1.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket‌​(PlainSocketFactory.‌​java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.op‌​enConnection(Default‌​ClientConnectionOper‌​ator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(M‌​anagedClientConnecti‌​onImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionM‌​anager$MeasuredConne‌​ction.open(Measuring‌​ConnectionManager.ja‌​va:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnec‌​t(DefaultRequestDire‌​ctor.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(D‌​efaultRequestDirecto‌​r.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(Abs‌​tractHttpClient.java‌​:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(Clos‌​eableHttpClient.java‌​:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(Clos‌​eableHttpClient.java‌​:55)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeR‌​equest(HTTPHC4Impl.j‌​ava:654)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(H‌​TTPHC4Impl.java:413)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sam‌​ple(HTTPSamplerProxy‌​.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.samp‌​le(HTTPSamplerBase.j‌​ava:1166)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.samp‌​le(HTTPSamplerBase.j‌​ava:1155)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(‌​JMeterThread.java:47‌​5)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeter‌​Thread.java:418)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java‌​:249)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: please add your error log and try to make a better description

Comment: I develop my rest service code is python django frame work.In Jmeter i can able to load Api 80 users at a time,but could not able to load 100 users,in this case Jmeter show above error.

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused error comes due to many reasons..

Please see the response code received in your JMeter listener (View Results Tree) . If its response code is 200, and you are getting this error it means there is an issue with your JMeter scripting then you should route your ideas towards proxy sever settings in JMeter, but if the response code is not 200, it means there is an issue with your application.